# configure logging of access successful & failures locally on ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, logging

Is it possible to configure log-in/access logging (success & fail) locally on ASA?

If it's possible how?

If it's not then should I use asdm or TACACS?

Comment: Do you mean (admin) user login to the ASA?

Comment: yes! logging for local user authentication success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco ASA can store logs locally but you will have much better results sending logs to an external syslog server.

It can also use external authentication like radius or tacacs+ but it can store events for local authentication if you want.
Take a look at these log events for authentication and command logging:

https://community.cisco.com/t5/network-security/audit-log-on-cisco-asa-firewall/td-p/3710864

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/syslog/b_syslog/syslogs1.html

Those should help you get started logging what you want but I would strongly recommend storing logs on a syslog server. Storing the logs in memory runs out quickly and you won't find what you want a lot of the time when you need to go back and look for it.

Comment: thx a lot! I solved this from your help! I appreciate it!